# LoadRunner combined with custom Java code to create saml tokens per vuser

Tags: java, customization, saml, loadrunner

Wanting to implement some custom Java code to create a saml token for each vuser in my http loadrunner vuser script I wonder how could this be set up? 
Lets say a developer could develop some code that generates a saml token to be used with every vuser request(s), can this be "called" per vuser? How would Loadrunner be set up to use custom Java code inside a vuser script? The scripts are in C but the code/logic to generate saml tokens is developed in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Several Paths are open

(1) Convert the Java Algorithm to a C function and then integrate with your C based virtual user.

(2) Convert your C based Web Virtual user to Java and then use the Java version of your code.   When you head down this path you will have to visit the dark magic realm associated with your version of Java, your version of LoadRunner, 32 bit vs 64 bit and how many gnomes need to be sacrificed in order for it to all work together seamlessly.

By the way, this challenge is not just with Java, it's also with .Net (to an even greater degree!).  It's caused by the speed at which the versions change on the language (Java, .Net variants) move faster than the tool vendors can keep up to support specific releases.

Comment: Ok, Sound like I want to go for the first (1) sugestion. Lets say I have someone to create a C function for mye algoritm (actually to generate saml tokens). Do I place this C function in globals.h ? And do I refer the function in the Action Block? Do you have a piece of code that shows how you call the C function (if it is in the globals.h) within the v user script?

Answer (score 0):

One option, which I've sometimes used, is:

- Write a Java servlet that encapsulates the functionality I want
- Run it on a web server somewhere (usually a Tomcat instance we've got running on one of our test rigs)
- Create a Web/HTTP script that uses the servlet
- Optionally, wrap it all up in a re-usable function.

It avoids the need to port any code from one language to the other, or to deal with LoadRunner's (somewhat flaky) Java support. Also, you might find that your organisation didn't buy enough (or indeed any) Java vuser licenses, but has plenty of Web/HTTP licenses.